# The Ricci quadratic form is a constant $\lambda$ iff $r = \lambda g$

Tags: differential-geometry

On page 3 of Arthur Besse’s book “Einstein Manifolds”, he writes:

> An easy argument shows that the Ricci quadratic form $r:UM \rightarrow \mathbb R$ [where $UM$ is the unit tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$] is a constant $\lambda$ if and only if $r=\lambda g$.

This function $r$, the “Ricci quadratic form”, is the diagonal restriction of the Ricci symmetric bilinear form and can be defined as $r(x) = \operatorname{Tr}(z\mapsto R(x,z)x)$, where $R$ is the Riemann curvature tensor.

What is the easy argument that $r$ is a constant iff $r = \lambda g$?

Comment: This is really a question in linear algebra. First fix a point in the manifold. Fix an orthonormal basis of the tangent space. Then you can write the metric Ricci tensor as a symmetric matrix and any tangent vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors. Write the formula for $r$ in terms of the matrix and the coefficients of any unit vector. Figure out what the matrix has to be if $r$ is constant for all unit tangent vectors.

Comment: @Deane, by “metric” Ricci tensor, do you mean the $(1,1)$-tensor $\operatorname{Ric}_a^b$ obtained from the Ricci curvature $r_{ac}$, which is a $(0,2)$-tensor, by raising one of its indices with the inverse metric $\operatorname{Ric}_a^b=r_{ac}g^{cb}$? $\operatorname{Ric}_a^b$ is a product of two symmetric matrices, but how do I see that it is also symmetric?

Comment: Have you studied what the Riemann and Ricci tensors are and their basic properties? Besse assumes you know all if that already.

Comment: @Deane, I’ve recently reviewed that material. I also see the gist of your argument, but I’m just struggling with writing it cleanly.

Comment: I think I got it: if the basis is orthonormal, then the metric is diagonal, so $\operatorname{Ric}_a^b$ is symmetric because it is the product of a symmetric matrix with a diagonal one.

Comment: Then you know that Ricci at each $x\in M$ is a symmetric tensor $\operatorname{Rc}$ and $r: T_x \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$ r(v) = \operatorname{Rc}(v,v)\text{ for any }v\in T_xM.$$ I’m suggesting you find the formula for $r$ with respect to an orthonormal basis of $T_xM$.